# PDO bind values not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to insert a value from my form into my SQL table.

Here's the form:

```
   <form action="index.php?id=" method="GET">
     <input id="Trigramme" name="Trigramme" type="text" value="<?php 
      if (empty($_GET['Trigramme'])):
          echo ('');
      else:
           echo ($_GET['Trigramme']);
      endif;
       ?>">
     <input id='idFormation' type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php 
      if ($formations['ID'] <= $maxIdFormation['Max_ID']):
          echo ($formations['ID']+1);
      else:
           echo ('1');
      endif;
       ?>">
     <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

And here's the function I use for the insertion:

```
function ajouterMembre($infosMembre){
    $pdo = getDb(); 

$requeteAjout = $pdo -> prepare ("INSERT INTO `users` ( `Trigramme`, `Formation_id`) VALUES (':Trigramme', ':Formation_id')");

$requeteAjout -> bindValue(':Trigramme', $infosMembre['Trigramme']);
$requeteAjout -> bindValue(':Formation_id', $infosMembre['id']);

$requeteAjout -> execute();

var_dump($requeteAjout);
var_dump( $infosMembre['id']);
var_dump( $infosMembre['Trigramme']);

return $pdo-> lastInsertId();

}
```

And lastly, this is the function I use in my HTML:

```
<?php $idNouveauMembre = ajouterMembre($_GET); ?>
```

The issue I have is that the SQL returns the values `Trigramme = :Trigramme` and `id = 0`.

I guess that my `bindValue` is not working properly. But when I try to check with:

```
var_dump( $infosMembre['id']);
var_dump( $infosMembre['Trigramme']);
```

it returns the correct values I want inserted.

Comment: You are not referencing the variable type.. see php manual [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and try again

Comment: You don't need the apostrophes in your query. VALUES (:Trigramme, :Formation_id)

Answer (score 0):

```
$requeteAjout = $pdo -> prepare ("INSERT INTO `users` ( `Trigramme`, `Formation_id`) VALUES (':Trigramme', ':Formation_id')");
```

replace that line of code with this

```
$requeteAjout = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` ( `Trigramme`, `Formation_id`) VALUES (:Trigramme, :Formation_id)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont add quotation marks around this :Formation_id and the other one too.

Answer (score 0):

remove single quotes in your `prepare` statement value:

```
$requeteAjout = $pdo -> prepare ("INSERT INTO `users` ( `Trigramme`, `Formation_id`) VALUES (:Trigramme, :Formation_id)");
```

Comment: When you get a chance, please edit your answer and add the code! The StackOverflow mods may delete your answer if it doesn't contain the code for the solution.

Comment: Thank you all :D